# A low class (restaurant / bar / hotel) in AE

Tags: word-request

As you know, Americans call a high class restaurant, bar, hotel or other places a "posh restaurant..."
How do the Americans call a low class one?

Comment: I don't think I have ever heard the word "posh" used by an American.

Comment: @StoneyB: Between driving around in monster trucks and spitting on the floor, who's got the time to learn dorky words, dude. That said, I once knew a guy from St. Louis who didn't know what OTSL stood for.

Comment: @Ricky Not me, man: I was the BO manager for OTSL's very first season; I still remember the *Albert Herring* as the best-acted piece I've ever seen from an opera company.

Comment: @StoneyB: I loathe Britten, but apart from that, kudos to you, man.

Comment: Yep, "dive" is a good one in American English. Source: Born and raised American.

Comment: In such dilemma, 'not/non (so) x' comes to our rescue! So... *not-so-posh!* ^-^

Answer (score 9, accepted):

***Posh*** is an ironic word. Use it with great care if you don't wish to be misunderstood.

That said, the opposite of a high-class restaurant would be

a dive
a grease pit
a burger joint
a greasy spoon:

depending on what, exactly, you wish to convey.

The antonyms of *posh* can be found in the thesaurus. Oh, and any establishment can be safely called a dump.

Comment: I knew the word "dive" but I was not sure that if Americans use it or not. Thank you very much Ricky. It was helpful

Comment: @A-friend: Any time, chief.

Comment: I think I'm more familiar with the term "dive bar," but clearly I understood what was meant. Excellent answer. I've also been enlightened.

Answer (score 6):

To add to Ricky's comment:

a [**hole-in-the-wall**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/hole-in-the-wall)

> [US] a ​small, often ​unpleasant, ​shop, ​house, or ​restaurant:
>
> It's just a ​hole in the ​wall but the ​food is good.

Comment: I've never heard hole-in-the-wall used to indicate unpleasantness, just small size. It may be a regionalism.

Comment: See also [Eng lang and Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275268/what-is-the-name-of-a-small-unluxurious-restaurant/275270#275270)